# JvM heap size is not cleaning after session times out

Tags: jvm, heap-memory

We have architecture where user access the dashboard in two step:

1. Create User session (iServer Session) with web Services (Server to Server Call)
2. Fetching the docuemnt with appending same user session from client browser.

Other Info

1. Total of document sizes is about 5MB
2. JVM Heap Size 8GB

Issue:

When we are starting the load test with 10 users, the jvm heap size increases and it reaches to max in no time with new load injection.

Where there is logout or session time out, the user session times out but the memory in the heap remained same.

Thereby, performance of dashboards decreases and getting time out once heap reaches max.

Can someone please throw more light, how we can on this.

Comment: You need to determine the cause of the timeouts. Is it due to the GC pauses, or because you ran out of memory, or due to something else.  DO you have a memory leak?  How much memory is free after a full GC?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I checked the standalone code, there is no memory leak. Find the below snaps for GC memory dump
14:58:01  GC 98304K-19352K(376832K), 0.1022679 secs
14:58:02  GC 128961K-46753K(376832K), 0.1587265 secs
14:58:03  GC 117656K-31321K(475136K), 0.1105521 secs
14:58:05  GC 145057K-73316K(475136K), 0.3917156 secs
14:58:06  GC 227929K-94817K(475136K), 0.3401635 secs
14:58:08  GC 291425K-204430K(671744K), 0.5125246 secs
14:58:10  GC 269924K-151196K(475136K), 0.1762976 secs
14:58:10  Full GC 204430K-73674K(751616K), 1.4817849 secs

Comment: To see if there is a memory leak you need to look at how much memory is used after a full GC. However, you do appear to have a tuning problem as a Full GC of 204 MB shouldn't take 1.48 seconds, that suggests a problem.